# Using streamslice/quiver and inpolygon crop

Tags: matlab

Suppose we have quiver field i.e. we have a meshgrid and then we assign a vector to each point. Is it possible to plot only the quiver field within some polygon?

So in the figure below, we want everything outside the triangle to be cropped out.

[image]

Ideally the code will also be helpful for the next step of having multiple such polygons and cropping out everything on their complement.

Some approaches:

- A direct way is to figure out the meshgrid for the particular polygon and then assign a vector to each point. But that will take a lot of time to figure out as polygons get more complicated. In other words, the regular meshgrid is the square polygon, so we must modify the meshgrid matrix depending on our polygon. A friend informed me of [a mesh generator matlab code](https://popersson.github.io/pub/persson04mesh_col.pdf).
- Use inpolygon.  The input of inpolygon are points in (x,y). But in our case we only have the vector field assigned to a meshgrid. One idea is to solve the ode system to obtain concrete solution pairs (x,y) to plug into the polygon. But solving them takes a lot longer and the pictures are not as nice.

Comment: Do you want to crop it as in a picture, or you really want the data in the polygon? i.e., a third approach may be to cover all unwanted area within the axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some sample code which I think will generate the kind of plot you want. It uses `inpolygon` to "filter" out the points inside the polygon. The vector field is still evaluated at the original `meshgrid` points. It easily extends to multiple polygons too.

```
clear
clc
x = linspace(0, 1, 21);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,x);

U = -Y; %some velocity field
V = X;

hold off
quiver(X,Y,U,V); %quiver on all points

polygon = [0.2,0.2;
           0.7,0.5;
           0.5,0.8]; %polygon vertices

ind = inpolygon(X,Y,polygon(:,1),polygon(:,2)); %get indices of points inside polygon

hold on
quiver(X(ind),Y(ind),U(ind),V(ind)); %quiver of points inside polygon
```